# export panel data to PDF and CSV format in primefaces ?(not datatable)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, panel

```
        <p:panel id="panelwv" style="padding:0px;right:600px;"
                                widgetVar="panelwv" visible="false" closable="true"
                                toggleable="true">

                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText value="Save&nbsp;as&nbsp;&nbsp;" />
                                    <h:commandLink>
                                        <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/csv.png" />
                                        <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="panelwv"
                                            fileName="Monthly_Summary" />
                                    </h:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                    <h:commandLink>
                                        <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/pdf.png" />
                                        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="panelwv"
                                            fileName="Monthly_Summary" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
      </p:panel>
```

The panel having dynamic data.I want to export data pdf and csv format.I am using `<p:dataExporter>` tag in primefaces but it is showing unsupported datasource error.please suggest any solution to export data in `<p:panel>`.

Comment: This is just not supported... And for 'suggestions' how to export pdf pages, try google. Something like xhtmlrenderer might help

Comment: It still is not supported, not for panelgrid, not for panel, not for anything but datatable and (afaik) treetable and datalist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just not possible as stated in the [fine documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_3.pdf):

> Target must point to a PrimeFaces Datatable.

It is there for a reason... Use it!